# Ripley and Ash's company orders: further mysteries

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979, aliens-1986

Recalling this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139213/why-didnt-ripley-explain-that-ashs-malfunction-was-caused-by-company-orders) about why Ripley didn't mention Ash (either at the company enquiry or to the Marines) it is also confusing that at the end of Alien, Ripley, after she blasts the alien into space and just before she went into the freezerino's with Jones the cat, notes "the crew who have been killed include "Kane,Lambert, Brett, Ash and Captain Dallas have been killed". Though she seemed to say Ash's name with some disdain, why not mention "Oh, by the way, Ash was a homicidal android acting on company orders to ensure the company had a new weapon for its weapons division"? Often authors try and get around and explain plot holes, did the Alan Dean Foster novelisation address this?

Comment: Are you assuming that everything that is shown on screen is the sum total of Ripley's communication with either the company inquest, or the marines? How do you know she did not say "Oh, by the way, Ash was a homicidal android acting on company orders to ensure the company had a new weapon for its weapons division" in exactly those words, but just not on screen? Maybe the author made a choice about what dialog made for the best story?

Comment: This was an important plot point and I would have thought it reasonable for Ripley to mention it on screen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the end of *Alien*, we're rejoining the action after she's spent some time checking that the ship is in good order, repressurising the hull, navigating towards Network Space, etc etc.

It's pretty clear that her log entry is considerably longer than just the snippet that we're hearing and almost certainly mentions both the Xenomorph as well as her feelings about the Ash, the Company and what's happened.

> INT. NARCISSUS - LATER
>
> Now repressurized.
> Ripley is seated in the control chair.
> Calm and composed, almost cheerful.
> Cat purring in her lap.
> She dictates into a recorder.
>
> **RIPLEY:** I should reach the frontier in another five weeks.  With a little luck the network will pick me up...This is Ripley, W564502460H, executive officer, last survivor of the commercial starship Nostromo signing off. (pause) Come on cat.
>
> <sub><sup>[Alien: Shooting Script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/alien_shooting.html)</sup></sub>

Unfortunately, for her, we learn (in *Aliens*) that all of this info was erased by [WY](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Weyland-Yutani_Corporation) technicians before her board of enquiry took place, leaving only the very barest of details about the official orders given to MUTHR.